# Download a zip file created entirely in memory with Django

Tags: django, zip

I need to generate several csv reports, compress and serve as zip to the user. I'm using [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/) as reference

```
    ...
    temp = StringIO.StringIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(temp,'w') as archive:
        for device in devices:
            csv = Mymodel.get_csv_for(device)
            archive.writestr('{}_device.csv'.format(device), str(csv))

    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(temp), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="devices.zip"')

    return response
```

Looking at the `archive.listname()` i can see the file names.
Looking at `temp.getvalue()` i can see some string but when I download the file it comes out empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `temp.seek(0)` before returning the response, otherwise Python will try to read the memory file from its end (where you left it at after writing the archive to it) and therefore will not find any content and return an empty HTTP response.

You also need to use a `StreamingHttpResponse` instead of a `HttpResponse`.

That would give:

```
...
temp = StringIO.StringIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(temp,'w') as archive:
    for device in devices:
        csv = Mymodel.get_csv_for(device)
        archive.writestr('{}_device.csv'.format(device), str(csv))

response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(temp), content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="devices.zip"')
response['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()

temp.seek(0)

return response
```

Comment: It is working on my computer, do you still receive an empty file?

Comment: Yes. I still get an empty file.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a `Content-Length` header to the response. What value does it have?

Comment: So you mean the response does not have a `Content-Length` header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75812/discussion-between-aumo-and-haki).